# Counting number of transactions within past 1 hour on a particular user

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

Is there any way how to (in the best case, without using cursor) count number of transactions that the same user made in previous 1 hour.

That means that for this table

```
CREATE TABLE #TR (PK INT, TR_DATE DATETIME, USER_PK INT)

INSERT INTO #TR VALUES (1,'2018-07-31 06:02:00.000',10)
INSERT INTO #TR VALUES (2,'2018-07-31 06:36:00.000',10)
INSERT INTO #TR VALUES (3,'2018-07-31 06:55:00.000',10)
INSERT INTO #TR VALUES (4,'2018-07-31 07:10:00.000',10)
INSERT INTO #TR VALUES (5,'2018-07-31 09:05:00.000',10)
INSERT INTO #TR VALUES (6,'2018-07-31 06:05:00.000',11)
INSERT INTO #TR VALUES (7,'2018-07-31 06:55:00.000',11)
INSERT INTO #TR VALUES (8,'2018-07-31 07:10:00.000',11)
INSERT INTO #TR VALUES (9,'2018-07-31 06:12:00.000',12)
```

The result should be:

[image]

The solution could be something like: COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY USER_PK ORDER BY TR_DATE ROWS BETWEEN ((WHERE DATEADD(HH,-1,PRECENDING.TR_DATE) > CURRENT ROW.TR_DATE) AND CURRENT ROW ...but I know that ROWS BETWEEN can not be used like that...

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing SQL Server based on the syntax.  In SQL Server, you can use `apply`:

```
select t.*, tr2.result
from #tr tr outer apply
     (select count(*) as result
      from #tr tr2
      where tr2.user_id = tr.user_id and
            tr2.tr_date > dateadd(hour, -1, tr.date) and
            tr2.tr_date <= tr.tr_date
     ) tr2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT USER_PK, COUNT(*) AS TransactionCount
FROM #TR
WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TR_DATE, GETDATE()) <= 60
AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TR_DATE, GETDATE()) >= 0
GROUP BY USER_PK
```

You can change `GETDATE()` with whatever you want, but they need to have the same value

Comment: This solution gives you another result. The solution should be something like:
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY USER_PK ORDER BY TR_DATE ROWS BETWEEN ((WHERE DATEADD(HH,-1,PRECENDING.TR_DATE) > CURRENT ROW.TR_DATE) AND CURRENT ROW
...but I know that ROWS BETWEEN can not be used like that...

Comment: have you reached a solution yet? Please, improve your expected result